# Style based on login status

Tags: templates, sitefinity

I'm trying to style a Login/logout button widget to be one style logged in and another logged out. I'm currently thinking there might be a special value I could put in as a class to determine whether the user is logged in (e.g. something like `{isLoggedIn}`), but I'm not sure if there is such a thing.

Is there anything I could used like this? Otherwise I guess I might just add 2 buttons to the template but only have them appear when the user is logged in/out. That way I could apply a custom class to each.

I can't believe that it should be that complex, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the template that the Sitefinity login widget uses, then figure out if the current user is authenticated or not and if so, output an "isLoggedIn" class somewhere.

To override the template the Sitefinity login widget uses, you'll first need to download the default template from the SDK. Those widget templates are [here](https://github.com/Sitefinity-SDK/SitefinityResources/tree/master/Templates). You can find the login widget template using this path: \WidgetTemplates\Templates\PublicControls\LoginWidget.ascx

Copy the control and add it to your project, I usually create a "WidgetTemplates" folder in the event you need to do this for another widget.

Edit the LoginWidget.ascx control and at the top import the following namespace:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Claims" %>
```

Then while still editing the control, search for the div that has the "sfSubmitBtnWrp" class and edit the markup to the following:

```
<div class="sfSubmitBtnWrp <%= ClaimsManager.GetCurrentIdentity().IsAuthenticated ? "isLoggedIn" : string.Empty %>">
```

This will output your "isLoggedIn" class to that wrapper div if the current user is authenticated so you can apply different styling to the submit button.

To tell Sitefinity to use your widget template, edit the page with the login widget and then edit your login widget. In the LayoutTemplatePath field, enter in the path to your widget, so if you added it to a "WidgetTemplates" folder, it should be "~/WidgetTemplates/LoginWidget.ascx"

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. Now I'm just wondering if I can use that code in the master template to apply a class - there's more than one thing that is styled based on login status so it would be convenient

Comment: When you say master template, are you referring to a Sitefinity page template? If so, do you have it running off a .master page?

Comment: Yeah, that one. I'm writing the .master page and the template from scratch.

Comment: Accepted your answer because despite the fact I didn't use it, it's still nicer than the way I did it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have much time, and I found a terrible terrible way of doing this that is terrible.

Instead of Ben's very good suggestion, I just banged a login/logout button (actually it could be anything) with a named class right at the top of the template outside of all my wrappers, gave it `display:none` and revoked permissions to anonymous users.

Now I can just prefix any logged in styling with `.login-status ~ #wrapper` and it only applies when the user is logged in.

Edit: Actually, I decided to go with an empty content block so it wasn't so intrusive in the HTML.